# Which file on a USB live installation made with UNetBootin persists file information?

Tags: live-usb, persistence, unetbootin

I created an installation of Ubuntu 11.10 using UNetBootin on a usb thumbdrive.

I've downloaded programs and installed them with apt-get so that they persist on the drive between boots.

What file stores these persisted files, if you were to look at it on a computer that had not been booted from the thumbdrive?

Comment: I suppose you want to increase the peristance space? , why didn't you set it with Unetbootin?.

Comment: No I don't want to increase the persistence space. I want to be able to backup the persistence file and use it again if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Should I close this out or just answer my own question?

Comment: Have you found your solution? if so post it as the answer and later accept it.

Comment: Ahh my bad I wrote the last comment on the wrong question.  Sorry.

Comment: Is it something like ./casper/filesystem.squashfs?

Comment: Nope, that's the File system the Live enviroment uses.

Comment: @UriHerrera I just mounted ./casper/filesystem.squashfs and you're right, it has all of the files to run the OS but it doesn't have any of the files in /home/

Comment: Ah ha! I bet it's casper-rw ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay after a bit of googling to figure out what I was looking for exactly...

```
sudo mkdir /media/casper
sudo mount ./casper-rw /media/casper -o loop
```

And now I can mount it and get back at my files again.

Comment: Good finding, +1.