# Formatted casper-rw - schoolboy error

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, data-recovery

Please don't laugh, a bit of an embarrassing question here.

I'm rather new to Ubuntu (12.04) and run it from a USB stick.
I didn't understand (or check!) what casper-rw was, and did a 'format' on it.
I got some strange error, so hoped I hadn't broken anything.
Ubuntu still worked but then failed to boot then next time I restarted (insert sad face here).

I renamed casper-rw using a Windows 7 PC to casper-rw-old, and used a Windows utility to recreate a casper-rw. I can now boot again but obviously have lost my files which are, I now realise, residing within casper-rw-old.

Are the files gone or can I recover them somehow?
I tried to mount casper-rw-old but got an error.
Here is what I tried and the output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /media/casper-rw-old
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd /cdrom
ubuntu@ubuntu:/cdrom$ sudo mount -o loop casper-rw-old /media/casper-rw-old
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
ubuntu@ubuntu:/cdrom$ sudo mount -o loop -t ext2 casper-rw-old /media/casper-rw-old
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

ubuntu@ubuntu:/cdrom$ dmesg | tail
[  832.568463] SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on loop2
[  832.588362] EXT2-fs (loop2): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev loop2.
[ 1198.328744] EXT2-fs (loop2): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev loop2.
[ 1659.402557] EXT3-fs (loop2): error: can't find ext3 filesystem on dev loop2.
[ 1659.420516] EXT4-fs (loop2): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1659.488706] FAT-fs (loop2): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 1659.488723] FAT-fs (loop2): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 1659.504565] SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on loop2
[ 1659.524461] EXT2-fs (loop2): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev loop2.
[ 1678.324199] EXT2-fs (loop2): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev loop2.
ubuntu@ubuntu:/cdrom$
```

Is there anything I can run to recover the files from casper-rw-old?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173670/finding-out-what-filesystem-a-casper-rw-file-is-formated-with

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the casper-rw file, (and in your case the casper-rw-old file).

First CD to the location where the casper-rw files are located.

(in my case this was cd /media/cscameron/LIVE-LINUX)

Then make a directory to mount casper-rw-old in:

```
sudo mkdir /media/casper-old
```

Then mount it:

```
sudo mount -o loop casper-rw-old /media/casper-old/
```

Make another directory for casper-rw

```
sudo mkdir /media/casper
```

Mount casper-rw

```
sudo mount -o loop casper-rw /media/casper/
```

And copy all of the files from the casper-rw-old file to the mounted blank casper-rw file

I am not quite sure how this differs from what you did, perhaps cd'ing to media rather than to cdrom.
I am doing this while booted from internal drive, (or Live DVD), not from the persistent USB.